# MYSQL query for one to many relation

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many

i have two tables:-

1- **section**

```
id    name   location_id
1     demo1     20
2     demo2     34
```

2- **amenities**

```
id    amenity_id   amenity_type object_id object_type

1   wedding_hall    venue_type     1          section

2  conference_hall  venue_type     1          section

3  conference_hall  venue_type     2          section
```

i want all those section whose location_id is 134 and who has wedding_hall and conference hall both. I have tried this query:-

```
    SELECT s.* from section s 
    INNER JOIN amenities am 
  on (am.object_type='section' AND am.object_id=s.id) 
WHERE s.location_id=134 AND 
(am.amenity_type LIKE 'venue_type' and am.amenity_id='wedding_hall') 
AND (am.amenity_type LIKE 'venue_type' and am.amenity_id='conference_hall')
```

if i do this query:-

```
     SELECT s.* from section s 
 INNER JOIN amenities am 
on (am.object_type='section' AND am.object_id=s.id)
 WHERE s.location_id=134 AND 
(am.amenity_type LIKE 'venue_type' and am.amenity_id='wedding_hall')
```

then it works bot not for more than one amenity.
here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c111f/1)

how can i correct my query?

Comment: In your sample data, these is no section which its location_id is 134. Or it's  a typo?

Comment: @10086 its just a typo. there is no syntax error in my actual query, i am not  just finding the right result.

Comment: Review your usage of LIKE; there are no wildcard characters. Update your example with relevant data. 134 is not mentioned in your example data

Comment: @JeroenHeier i have added sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I did not mistake your question and you really want section which id = 1, try this:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM section s
INNER JOIN amenities am
ON am.object_type='section' AND am.object_id=s.id
WHERE s.location_id=134
AND am.amenity_type LIKE 'venue_type'
AND am.amenity_id IN ('wedding_hall', 'conference_hall')
-- HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT am.amenity_id) > 1
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT am.amenity_id) = 2
```

#### SQLFiddle Demo

Comment: its working, i want to clear my doubt that if it will give result only if it has wedding_hall and conferernce_hall both?

Comment: I think it could also give results if it has two wedding halls or two conference halls.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava Then it should be `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT am.amenity_id) = 2`, check my answer.

Comment: @10086 its working for one section but if i have more than one section with both amenties its giving me only one section as result:- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10a3cf/5

Comment: Then add `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need subqueries for that. Maybe take a look at the `EXISTS` condition. The following will give you the desired result if the section has both wedding hall and conference hall (but not if you have just two wedding halls, and it's working with more than one section):

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.* FROM section s
    INNER JOIN amenities a
    ON a.object_id = s.location_id
        WHERE s.location_id = 134
    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM amenities WHERE object_id = s.location_id AND amenity_id = 'wedding_hall')
    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM amenities WHERE object_id = s.location_id AND amenity_id = 'conference_hall');
```

Maybe add amenity_type and object_type conditions to the `WHERE` clauses.